# How to work with async code in Mongoose virtual properties?

Tags: asynchronous, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to work with associating documents in different collections (not embedded documents) and while there is an [issue for that](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/188) in Mongooose, I'm trying to work around it now by lazy loading the associated document with a virtual property as documented [on the Mongoose website](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/virtuals.html).

The problem is that the getter for a virtual takes a function as an argument and uses the return value for the virtual property. This is great when the virtual doesn't require any async calls to calculate it's value, but doesn't work when I need to make an async call to load the other document. Here's the sample code I'm working with:

```js
TransactionSchema.virtual('notebook')
  .get( function() { // <-- the return value of this function is used as the property value
    Notebook.findById(this.notebookId, function(err, notebook) {
      return notebook; // I can't use this value, since the outer function returns before we get to this code
    })
    // undefined is returned here as the properties value
  });
```

This doesn't work since the function returns before the async call is finished. Is there a way I could use a flow control library to make this work, or could I modify the first function so that I pass the findById call to the getter instead of an anonymous function?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code sample, hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: And I see Josh managed to give you async code, see.

Comment: The problem you are running into is simply a "limitation" of JS combined with the way that Mongoose wrote the `get` method for virtuals to be synchronous. It expects a function that returns a value and no flow control library is ever going to be able to let you put async inside of it and have it work as expected. You'll run into the same thing if you tried to do async inside of a Underscore/lodash callback. Thus the need for Josh's solution that rolls its own asynchronous method and bypasses Mongoose's synchronous `get`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can define a virtual method, for which you can define a callback.

Using your example:

```
TransactionSchema.method('getNotebook', function(cb) {
  Notebook.findById(this.notebookId, function(err, notebook) {
    cb(notebook);
  })
});
```

And while the sole commenter appears to be one of those pedantic types, you also should not be afraid of embedding documents. Its one of mongos strong points from what I understand.

One uses the above code like so:

```
instance.getNotebook(function(nootebook){
    // hey man, I have my notebook and stuff
});
```

Comment: You can also cache the Notebook object locally to prevent multiple fetches from the DB, something like this:
`TransactionSchema.method('getNotebook', function(cb) {
  if (this._notebook) return cb(notebook);
  
  Notebook.findById(this.notebookId, function(err, notebook) {
    this._notebook = notebook;
    cb(notebook);
  })
});`

Comment: but is it possible to use this pattern in a virtual such that TransactionSchema.virtual('notebook').get(function()) called the method 'getNotebook' and returned results? the callback doesn't seem to work in that context.

Comment: @Greg, exactly. While this is a good solution for the question, it's not if what you really need is an asynchronous virtual field. But I believe asynchronous getters/setters are not possible in JS.

Comment: Mongoose should really put a HUGE disclaimer in their docs saying that async queries and functions do not work with regular "get" virtual fields. I spent hours looking for this solution.

Comment: @Benji the whole project should have a disclaimer. Having troubles daily with this library.

Answer (score 6):

While this addresses the broader problem rather than the specific question, I still thought it was worth submitting:

You can easily load an associated document from another collection (having a nearly identical result as defining a virtual) by using Mongoose's query [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) function. Using the above example, this requires specifying the ref of the ObjectID in the `Transaction` schema (to point to the Notebook collection), then calling `populate(NotebookId)` while constructing the query. The linked Mongoose documentation addresses this pretty thoroughly.

I'm not familiar with Mongoose's history, but I'm guessing `populate` did not exist when these earlier answers were submitted.

Comment: imhe this has always worked out best for me. simplest to implement and maintain

Answer (score 4):

Josh's approach works great for single document look-ups, but my situation was a little more complex.  I needed to do a look-up on a nested property for an entire array of objects.  For example, my model looked more like this:

```
var TransactionSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  , notebooks: {type: [Notebook]}
});

var NotebookSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  , authorName: String  // this should not necessarily persist to db because it may get stale
  , authorId: String
});

var AuthorSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: String
  , lastName: String
});
```

Then, in my application code (I'm using Express), when I get a Transaction, I want all of the notebooks with author last name's:

```
...
TransactionSchema.findById(someTransactionId, function(err, trans) {
  ...
  if (trans) {
    var authorIds = trans.notebooks.map(function(tx) {
        return notebook.authorId;
      });

    Author.find({_id: {$in: authorIds}, [], function(err2, authors) {
      for (var a in authors) {
        for (var n in trans.notebooks {
          if (authors[a].id == trans.notebooks[n].authorId) {
            trans.notebooks[n].authorLastName = authors[a].lastName;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      ...
    });
```

This seems wildly inefficient and hacky, but I could not figure out another way to accomplish this.  Lastly, I am new to node.js, mongoose, and stackoverflow so forgive me if this is not the most appropriate place to extend this discussion.  It's just that Josh's solution was the most helpful in my eventual "solution."

Comment: You could make a map of {_id: model} and avoid additional loop. Object.keys(map) would then return you IDs.

Answer (score 3):

As this is an old question, I figured it might use an update.

To achieve asynchronous virtual fields, you can use [mongoose-fill](https://github.com/whitecolor/mongoose-fill), as stated in mongoose's github issue: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1894