# Setting a virtual field in a Model based on an async query from another model

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to have a user setting (in a user model) that is derived from the sum of values in another model.

What I have tried to do is create a virtual value using a query like this:

```
var schemaOptions = {
    toObject: {
        virtuals: true
    }
    ,toJSON: {
        virtuals: true
    }
};
/**
 * User Schema
 */

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  email: String,
  username: String,
  provider: String,
  phonenumber: Number,
  country: String,
  emailverificationcode: {type:String, default:'verifyme'},
  phoneverificationcode: {type:Number, default:4321 },
  emailverified: {type:Boolean, default:false},
  phoneverified: {type:Boolean,default:false},
}, schemaOptions)

UserSchema
    .virtual('credits')
    .get(function(){
        //Load Credits model
        var Credit = mongoose.model('Credit');
        Credit.aggregate([
            { $group: {
                _id: '5274d0e5a84be03f42000002',
                currentCredits: { $sum: '$amount'}
            }}
        ], function (err, results) {
                if (err) {
                    return 'N/A'
                } else {
                    return results[0].currentCredits.toString();
                    //return '40';
                }
            }
        );
    })
```

Now, this gets the value but it fails to work correctly (I cannot retrieve the virtual 'value' credits). I think this is because of the async nature of the call.

Can someone suggest the correct way to achieve this?

Once again many thanks for any input you can provide.

Edit:

So I am trying to follow the suggested way but no luck so far. I cannot get my 'getCredits' method to call.

Here is what I have so far:

```
UserSchema.method.getCredits = function(cb) {
        //Load Credits model
        var Credit = mongoose.model('Credit');
        Credit.aggregate([
            { $group: {
                _id: '5274d0e5a84be03f42000002',
                currentCredits: { $sum: '$amount'}
            }}
        ], function (err, results) {
                cb(results);
            }
        );
};


var User = mongoose.model('User');

User.findOne({ _id : req.user._id })
.exec(function (err, tempuser) {
    tempuser.getCredits(function(result){

    });
})
```

Any ideas? Thanks again

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077601/how-to-work-with-async-code-in-mongoose-virtual-properties)

Comment: Thanks robertklep, I tried the solution suggested here but couldnt get my aggregate function to work. Ill try again to see Im making an error

Comment: I just cant get my 'getCredits' method to work.. sigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your implementation:

```
UserSchema.method.getCredits
           ^^^^^^ should be 'methods'
```

Also, you have to make sure that you add methods (and virtuals/statics) to your schema *before* you create the model, otherwise they won't be attached to the model.

So this isn't going to work:

```
var MySchema = new mongoose.Schema(...);
var MyModel  = mongoose.model('MyModel', MySchema);

MySchema.methods.myMethod = ... // too late, model already exists
```

Instead, use this:

```
var MySchema = new mongoose.Schema(...);

MySchema.methods.myMethod = ... 

var MyModel  = mongoose.model('MyModel', MySchema);
```

I would also advise you to always check/propagate errors.

Comment: Solved my problem perfectly. Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me.