# How to execute async functions in mongoose virtuals/middleware

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3, mongoose

I store images in S3, and just store their key in my MongoDB. When querying documents from MongoDB, I need the key to be transformed into a usable URL. I do this by calling getSignedUrl() from the AWS SDK. I was using a virtual for this:

```
MySchema.virtual('imageUrl').get(async function(this: MyDoc) {
  if (!this.imageKey) {
    return null;
  }
  const readUrl = await awsPreSignReadUrl(this.imageKey);
  return readUrl;
});
```

However, getSignedURL() is async, and virtuals don't seem to work with async code.

I know I can use a method instead and call it 'manually' every time I need it. However, this code needs to execute every time documents in this schema are queried (whether that's through find, findOne, aggregate, populate, etc.), so I need a solution that works automatically for all operations.

Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to work with async code in Mongoose virtual properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077601/how-to-work-with-async-code-in-mongoose-virtual-properties)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary thanks, it's helpful! Doesn't solve the problem, but reading through it, it seems this is a JS/mongoose limitation so I will have to find a hacky way to get around it