Unable to return a value inside a virtual.get() async function
Trying to add a virtual property on a model and set it's value as shown below:
const virtualCatName = testSchema.virtual("categoryName");
virtualCatName.get(async function(){     
    const catByID = await Category.findById(this.categoryId);   
    console.log(catByID.name);
    return catByID.name;
});
 

The console.log() seems to output the value correctly, however returning the same value doesnt seem to set the virtual property's value in the response JSON.
The JSON response:
...
...
"id": "666f4807902d3010e5cbcccf",
"categoryName": {},
...
...

what am i missing?

i'd assume .get is expecting a function that returns a value, rather than a function that returns a promise.

Possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077601/how-to-work-with-async-code-in-mongoose-virtual-properties
